# Period of a Dynamics System

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the following rule:
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-sign(Ax_k)$$
for $x_k\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2*2}$. Let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3/2&-1/2\\ -1/2&3/2\end{bmatrix}$$
How to prove that for sufficiently large $n$, $x_{n+2}=x_n$?

What I know: $\sigma(A)=\{1,2\}$, then
$$x_{k+1}^TAx_{k+1}\leq x_k A x_k -2 ||Ax_k||_1 + 4,$$
then for sufficiently large $n$, we have $ 
||Ax_k||_1\leq 2$.
Moreover, $x_k$ can only flow along the "grid," so at the end, $x$ must be periodic.
But how to show the period is 2?

Comment: What do you mean by $\ sign(Ax)\ $? Should that be $\ sign(Ax_k)\ $?  If so, then $\ Ax_k\ $ will be a $\ 2\times1\ $ column vector. Is $\ sign(Ax_k)\ $ the $\ 2\times1\ $ column vector obtained by applying the *sign* operation componentwise to the components of $\ Ax_k\ $?

Comment: Yes, sign operation componentwise